# How to load abstract syntax tree of a python module by its name?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Let's say the name of the module is available in form of a string rather than module object. How do I locate its source code location and load the abstract syntax tree (if the source code is present)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take the problem in three steps:

1. Import the module by name. This should be relatively easy using [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module), though you could bodge up your own version with the builtin `__import__` if you needed to.
2. Get the source code for the module. Using [`inspect.getsource`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) is probably the easiest way (but you could also just try `open(the_module.__file__).read()` and it is likely to work).
3. Parse the source into an AST. This should be easy with [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse). Even for this step, the library isn't essential, as you can use the builtin `compile` instead, as long as you pass the appropriate flag (`ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST` appears to be `1024` on my system, so `compile(source, filename, 'exec', 1024)` should work).